# How hide rows in a range where the bounds of the range are variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide rows in a range, where the bounds of the range are variable. I know how to hide rows 5 thru 8 for example...

Rows("5:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True

But how do I do this, where StartHide and EndHide are integers? ...

Rows(StartHide:EndHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Construct the range to hide from your variables.

```
Rows(StartHide & ":" & EndHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Rows

- You can only hide **entire** rows.
- When the range is all the cells of a worksheet then you don't have to use `EntireRow` (first example).

**The Small Study**

```
Option Explicit

Sub hideRowsWorksheet()
    
    Const sHide As Long = 5
    Const eHide As Long = 8
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Rows(sHide).Resize(eHide - sHide + 1).Hidden = True
    End With

End Sub

' When first row is equal to 1.
Sub hideRowsRange()
    
    Const sHide As Long = 5
    Const eHide As Long = 8
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("A1:J10")
        With rg
            ' This will hide 'Rows("5:8")': (1,2,3,4,5). Note 'EntireRow'.
            .Rows(sHide).Resize(eHide - sHide + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
    End With

End Sub

' When first row is greater than 1.
Sub hideRowsRange2()
    
    Const sHide As Long = 5
    Const eHide As Long = 8
    
    With ActiveSheet
        
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("A7:J16")
        With rg
            ' This will hide 'Rows("11:14")' (7,8,9,10,11). Note 'EntireRow'.
            .Rows(sHide).Resize(eHide - sHide + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With

    End With

End Sub

' When range and worksheet rows are intersecting.
Sub hideRowsRange3()
    
    Const sHide As Long = 5
    Const eHide As Long = 8
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("A7:J16")
        With rg
            ' This will hide 'Rows("7:9")' (7,8,9,10,11)(5,6,7,8,9).
            ' Note the importance of the last occurrence of 'EntireRow'.
            Intersect(.Worksheet.Rows(sHide) _
                .Resize(eHide - sHide + 1), .EntireRow).EntireRow = True
        End With
        
    End With

End Sub

' When range and worksheet rows are intersecting (possible mistakes).
Sub hideRowsRange4()
    
    Const sHide As Long = 5
    Const eHide As Long = 8
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("A7:J16")
        With rg
            ' Although...
            Debug.Print .Worksheet.Rows(sHide).Resize(eHide - sHide + 1).Address
            Debug.Print .Worksheet.Rows(sHide) _
                .Resize(eHide - sHide + 1).EntireRow.Address
            Debug.Print rg.EntireRow.Address
            ' ...these do not work.
            On Error Resume Next
            Intersect(.Worksheet.Rows(sHide) _
                .Resize(eHide - sHide + 1), .EntireRow).Hidden = True
            Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
            Intersect(.Worksheet.Rows(sHide) _
                .Resize(eHide - sHide + 1).EntireRow, .EntireRow).Hidden = True
            Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```